# Azure blob storage compress archive

Tags: powershell, azure-blob-storage

I am working on archiving files once I'm done processing them. Each file is around 500 mb which is not a whole lot to start with and we have a retention period of 180 days and can add up pretty easily. I am looking at ways to compress the file and the [compress-archive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.archive/compress-archive?view=powershell-7.2) but not sure how to use it with `Start-AzStorageBlobCopy`

***PoSh:***

```
Start-AzStorageBlobCopy -SrcContainer "Upload" -SrcBlob "BlockBlobName" -DestContainer "Archive" -DestBlob "BlockBlobName_MMDDYYYY"
```

Answer (score 0):

`Start-AzStorageBlobCopy` performs a server-side async copy operation. Because of this reason you cannot use `Compress-Archive` with it. In order to save compressed content in blob storage, you will need to first download the blobs locally somewhere, compress them using `Compress-Archive` and then upload the compressed file again.

Comment: Hi @Gaurav Mantri Is there a way to use any other compression technique with `Start-AzStorageBlobCopy` without having to move files else where.

Comment: AFAIK, it is not possible to do so. Can you look at Azure Data Factory? May be it has something there to facilitate this.

Comment: We are not using Azure Data Factory and trying to minimize the movement of files especially to on-premise from cloud as we would end up using a whole lot of network bandwidth.

Comment: Understood and agreed on bandwidth minimization. Another alternative would be to use an Azure VM in the same region as that of your storage account for downloading, zipping and uploading the blobs.